# Why I am getting 0 when using rand? my values are with decimal places

Tags: php

```
$value = rand(0.1, 0.3);
```

then the output returns 0

Any answers that could fix this?

I already tried to use

```
$value = 0.01*rand(1, 3);
```

still I get 0

Comment: `$value = 0.01*rand(1, 3);
var_dump($value);` --- it's not `0`

Comment: What does number does "getrandmax()" output?

Comment: Sounds like you've got some other code not shown here where `$value` gets used as an integer.

Comment: The first one is 0 because rand only accepts INTEGERS. The second one... is not 0. It's a float, you sure you don't cast it to an int somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

The function rand(); only accepts integers and not float number values.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

[The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) says it all:

> `rand` — Generate a random integer

Because you are passing floats (`0.1` and `0.3`), they are converted to `int`s and the result is exactly as this:

```
rand(0, 0)
```

Proof of the conversion: http://ideone.com/osg97

On the basis of the above, the only result may be getting from `rand(0.1, 0.3)` is `0` (zero). To get something else, base it on integers.

### Solution

The solution is simple, just use integer for calculation. If you want function that is ready for your needs, you can use this code (`$places` is number of digits you want to calculate for after integral part):

```
function float_rand($start, $end, $places){
    $multiplier = pow(10, $places);
    return rand($start * $multiplier, $end * $multiplier) / $multiplier;
}
```

Proof: http://ideone.com/lfUhx